# Bag 2, 2011 set, ID 135149

Tags: building, instructions, set-identification

Can anyone identify this bag? It has in it what looks like the grill of a truck, or skis!

[image]

Blue jacket, fearful face, gray round piece.
Mainly black blue and white. 2011 printed on bag.

[image: enter image Second bag within the bag has some yellow pieces]

Comment: I KNOW IT'S 2011 BAG 2. THAT'S ALL I KNOW. SORRY FOR THE CAPITAL LETTERS!

Comment: Welcome to our site! It's good to get a new member. I'm going to edit out the all-caps, though, if that's okay.

Comment: So Parton, there is a little checkmark icon under the up vote/down vote counter on each answer, if you press it, it will turn green and you get a few points. Pressing it means that the answer you used it on is the one you accept. Just accept whatever seems to be the best or most accurate answer. The one that this post has looks like the right one!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set #75915-1: Jurassic World Pteranodon Capture

[image]

Comment: THATS IT!!! Thx!